# Is a list a data type or data structure?

Tags: list, python-3.8

I'm wondering if a list is a data structure or data type. Some people say that it's a data type, some say the other, and the rest says both. I googled the meaning of data structure and data type and it says(i think) that a data structure is a way to organize, store data and that enables efficient access and modification, and a data type is a classification that specifies which type of value a variable has and what type of mathematical, relational or logical operations can be applied to it without causing an error.
Correct me if I'm wrong and please tell me whether a list in Python 3.8 is a data type, structure, or both. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](https://docs.python.org/3.8/tutorial/datastructures.html) is pretty definitive. The page title is "Data Structures", and the second sentence of the page is:

> The list **data type** has some more methods.

So, both.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a list is a data structure or data type, use the following command:

```
x = ["apple", "pear", "peach", "plumb"]
print(f"Is a list? {type(x) is list}")
```